# Is There A Name For Matrices Formed By Appending Rows?

Tags: matrices, terminology

When we concatenate two matrices' columns, we get an *augmented matrix*.

When we concatenate two matrices' rows, we get a ____________ ?

Comment: Also augmented matrix (consider the transpose).

Comment: In general, a "block matrix" is a matrix obtained by appending smaller matrices

Comment: What is this obsession with a singular name for every irrelevant detail or property? Given the sheer number of those, the names would be lengthy and hard to memorize.